# Что это за пользователь __default__?

Tags: centos, centos7, redhat, selinux

Вывод команды `semanage login -l` немного меня смутил

Кроме пользователя root, были ещё два пользователя:

- __default__
- system_u

Что это за пользователи?

Answer (score 0):

**system_u** используется для запуска системных процессов во время инициализации системы.
**__default__** отвечает за права новых пользователей, которые по умолчанию создаются непривилегированными.